# Shelving on Rubble Stone Foundation

Tags: foundation, shelving

I am looking to build shelving, nothing fancy, for a basement wall. I want to go the easiest possible route and was thinking of nailing a couple 2x4's to the wall and attaching some shelving brackets to them with some plywood shelves. The difficult part is that the wall is a rubble stone foundation wall and because of its unevenness I'm not sure how easy it will be to level the 2x4's. Any ideas?

Comment: Clarify please: is the stone foundation acting as wall or floor in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to penetrate that wall at all nor especially hang anything off of it. It's really just meant to work vertically, not laterally.

The best & only right shelving method is to hang the shelving from the ceiling joists, then you can have as many as you want. 2x4's resting against the wall with a lot of weight is perfectly fine.

Comment: That makes sense. Any ideas for an easy way to build this out?

Comment: I hoped to get you in time. Assuming the ceiling isn't finished & joists are fully accessible: If joists are Parallel to the shelf, run a 2x4 up to the subfloor (floor shoulders against wiggle) & drill 2 bolt holes in tandem in the middle 1/3 of the joist or just screw-in the 2x4 with 4 3" deck screws. If the joists are Perpendicular to the shelf, then 2x4 blocking should be screwed in centrally between joists...2 screws per blocking end screwed through the joists & not toe-nailed, same as parallel after this. Repeat either for a 2-leg board for brackets or for a 4-leg shelf unit or cabinet.